# Using a Custom UserStore and RoleStore in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have implemented a custom RoleStore and a custom UserStore for my project that is using ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, EF 7, and Identity 3. However - I can't quite figure out how to configure identity to use my custom RoleStore and custom UserStore instead of the usual offering. How can I reconfigure the system to use my custom classes?

PS: I also have custom User and Role class.

### Solution

Here's what I ended up doing. First, I uninstalled the 'Identity Entity Framework' package from my project. This sent a few things missing, so I re-implemented them (read: copied them from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore)), and put them in a 'Standard' namespace to indicate they hadn't been customised. I now have a 'Security' namespace that contains the following:

- Standard

  - IdentityRole.cs
  - IdentityRoleClaim.cs
  - IdentityUser.cs
  - IdentityUserClaim.cs
  - IdentityUserLogin.cs
  - IdentityUserRole.cs
- **BuilderExtensions.cs**
- **IdentityDbContext.cs**
- **Resources.resx**
- **Role.cs**
- **RoleStore.cs**
- **User.cs**
- **UserStore.cs**

The items shown in bold contain project specific functionality.

The code that allows me to use the custom stores is in the 'BuilderExtensions' file, which contains the following class:

```
public static class BuilderExtensions
{
    public static IdentityBuilder AddCustomStores<TContext, TKey>(this IdentityBuilder builder)
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        builder.Services.TryAdd(GetDefaultServices(builder.UserType, builder.RoleType, typeof(TContext), typeof(TKey)));
        return builder;
    }

    private static IServiceCollection GetDefaultServices(Type userType, Type roleType, Type contextType, Type keyType)
    {
        var userStoreType = typeof(UserStore<,,,>).MakeGenericType(userType, roleType, contextType, keyType);
        var roleStoreType = typeof(RoleStore<,,>).MakeGenericType(roleType, contextType, keyType);
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddScoped(
            typeof(IUserStore<>).MakeGenericType(userType),
            userStoreType);
        services.AddScoped(
            typeof(IRoleStore<>).MakeGenericType(roleType),
            roleStoreType);
        return services;
    }
}
```

This then allows me to write the following in my Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddCustomStores<PrimaryContext, string>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And the custom store will be used. Note that PrimaryContext is the name of my whole-project DbContext. it inherits from IdentityDbContext.

### Discussion

I could have probably kept the 'Identity Entity Framework' package and saved myself duplicating the contents of the 'Standard' namespace, but I chose not to so that I can keep my identifiers short and unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this section
Reconfigure application to use new storage provider in [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

Specifically "If the default storage provider was included in your project, you must remove the default provider and replace it with your provider."

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new YourNewUserStore(context.Get<ExampleStorageContext>()));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'd come across that article but reconsidering it gave me a few ideas. In the end, I removed references to the Identity EF framework and implemented my own extension to the IdentityBuilder class. I had to implement a few of the classes in the Identity EF package, but it wasn't a considerable amount of code. I'll add details to my question so others can find it in the future.